What’s the most efficient way to get crystals in Hatsune Miku: Colourful Stage?
In Hatsune Miku: Colourful Stage, you can use crystals to pull characters from banners.
I never have that many crystals, and it takes a while to build up enough for a ten-pull (3,000 crystals are required).
What’s the most efficient way to get crystals?

I could just summarize reddit... But that feels lazy...? https://www.reddit.com/r/ProjectSekai/comments/10awx1r/can_someone_give_me_tips_on_how_to_get_crystals/
